# MySQL ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP not updating on boolean / enum changes

Tags: mysql

I've got this table:

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` varchar(36) COLLATE utf8mb3_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'uuid-will-be-generated',
  `createdAt` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT (now()),
  `updatedAt` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT (now()) ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `username` varchar(60) COLLATE utf8mb3_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `email` varchar(256) COLLATE utf8mb3_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `realName` varchar(60) COLLATE utf8mb3_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `password` varchar(256) COLLATE utf8mb3_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'no-password-specified',
  `passwordType` enum('bcrypt') COLLATE utf8mb3_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'bcrypt',
  `useAsDisplayName` enum('username','email','realName') COLLATE utf8mb3_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'username',
  `admin` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `developer` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `usernameIndex` (`username`),
  UNIQUE KEY `emailIndex` (`email`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb3 COLLATE=utf8mb3_unicode_ci
```

And if I update any varchar the updatedAt field updates. But if I update an enum/boolean field then it doesn't. I know it won't update if the data in an update is the same, but the data is different and it doesn't update. Using MySQL 8.0.32.

Anybody have any ideas?

Comment: Cannot reproduce. I tested on my instance of MySQL 8.0.32, and it works fine. The `updatedAt` column updates after each update to enum or boolean columns, as well as the varchar column.

Comment: @BillKarwin why do you have to be right all the time? Turns out its my app that was doing that, not MySQL. I should have tested at a lower level. =)

Comment: LOL — I'm glad you got your answer. My secret weapon is simple: I try to _test_ before I open my mouth. If I don't test, I usually make mistakes because I made some assumption that turned out not to be true.

Comment: I did test, I just didn't test at a low enough level. And that is my bad.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out it was my app not MySQL. I should have checked at a lower level.